# Dynamics CRM: Select multiple records to add to a grid

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, webresource

I have 1:N relationship between entity A and B. I want to have a grid on the form of entity A with a button on the right corner (something like the + button of the out of box crm grid) when I click it I want to see a model window showing a grid with all the records of entity B and I want to be able to select as many records as I want then click an Add button on the model window which would close the model window and refresh only the grid on the form A where the new associated records of entity B will be visible.

I think the only way to do it is to create an html web resource for the grid and the model window. Am I right? If so, how can I make my html web resource look like crm? Is there a framework out there that helps with developing html webresource that have the look and feel of crm?

Comment: When you press the + button (add existing) the popup window to add multiple records showing up when the relationship is not mandatory (after scrolling down & clicking lookup more records) is not enough?

Comment: https://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/11/19/fixing-the-sub-grid-user-experience-in-crm-2013/ for context check this..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Less clicks?

Comment: Thanks @Aryn Vinoth. Yes I want to achieve less clicks to add existing records to the grid or to add a brand new one. The link you mentioned is for removing the add existing functionality. I want to click the + button and have window with the list of exisiting records (i don't want to see the lookup field) and to be able to select some records and add them or to click a new button to create a new record. If I can't do that in one window then is it possible to use the solution you sent me to make the + button open a new record and I add another buttton to the grid to add existing records? thx

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is too broad (but doable) & invited with overflowing unsupported customizations.

I have shared the [Gareth Tucker blog](https://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/11/19/fixing-the-sub-grid-user-experience-in-crm-2013/) to show you direction in some supported way. (Read the healthy comments there as well)

MS gave us this subgrid to minimize the clicks only rather than Associated view navigation path. The inline lookup introduction is having both pros/cons.

My recommendations based on our above comments earlier: (these will keep you in supported zone)

Keeping the 'add new +' button & try to show 'add existing standard +' button as well (am not sure about this feasibility may be some tweak needed around display rule). Otherwise add another brand new button & invoking the "Lookup more records" modal dialog ([this may help](http://alagunellaikumar.blogspot.com/2015/11/displayshow-crm-default-lookuplookup.html?m=1)).

Or

Keeping 'add existing standard +' button only by following Gareth approach to hide 'add new' button. Anyway Modal dialog will have 'New' button to create new record.

But AFAIK, there is no supported/unsupported way to achieve [open lookup dialog directly](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/165070)